# UK visa refusal two times

Tags: visas, uk, serial-refusals

what i do to getting visas it is fst refusal they put me questions why a company airport-transfer the funds in my acc second time when am apply then clear customs-and-immigration officer with atta he d bank statement and letter heads every things but mention gud u clearly doubt said bangladeshi .my citizenship indian

[image]

Comment: Your question is pretty illegible.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a clear case of funds parking. Please see Gayot Fow's excellent guide at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/60813.

If you have been refused and you continue to apply, you could be seen as making frivolous applications and this will tarnish any future applications. Unless you circumstances have significantly changed, it's recommended to stop making applications until a period of time have elapsed.

Also, you should black out your name when uploading the documents.

Comment: I didn't know that we could do that @GayotFow. Will remember for next time. I guess when you edit, you can also edit the uploaded photo.